# Rails - Check if a date belongs to a certain month in where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

Using Rails 6.

I have an `ElectricityUsage` model, with a Date field, `date`. I want to extract all the values for `amount` only for the current month. How would I accomplish this?

What I immediately attempted was the following:

```rb
ElectricityUsage.where(habitat: current_user.reservations[0].room.habitat).where(date.month: Date.today.month)
```

But that obviously doesn't work, and it wouldn't even account for the year, either. My DB is running on PostgreSQL, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `where` with `Date.current.all_month`, which basically is just translated into a query using `BETWEEN` where the start date is the first day of the month and end date is the last one:

```
ElectricityUsage.where(habitat: current_user.reservations[0].room.habitat, date: Date.current.all_month)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
ElectricityUsage.where(habitat: current_user.reservations[0].room.habitat).where("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = ?", Date.current.month)
```

[PostgreSQL Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a delayed response but you can use [date_queries gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/date_queries)

```rb
model ElectricityUsage < ActiveRecord::Base
  date_queries_for :date
end
```

Then you can simply use ElectricityUsage.dates_in_this_month to find all the records that false in current month